# Is there a way to print an item from a List of Lists in Java?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, printing

I am trying to split each line from a text file using CSV format with "," as the delimitter, into **name** and **age** variables, and then print them out.

For example -

Input:

- file name - records.txt
- lily,3
- anton,5
- billy,4
- mary,1

Output:

- Name of file: records.txt
- Name: Lily, Age: 3 years
- Name: Anton, Age: 5 years
- Name: Billy, Age: 4 years
- Name: Mary, Age: 1 year

**My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to call 'singleRecord' from 'records'.**

```
public class FileManager {
private List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

public FileManager() {
}

public void pullRecordsFromFile(String fileName) {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName + ".txt"))) {
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String row = input.nextLine();

            String[] parts = row.split(",");
            String name = parts[0];
            String age = parts[1];

            ArrayList<String> singleRecord = new ArrayList<String>();
            singleRecord.add(name);
            singleRecord.add(age);

            records.add(singleRecord);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void printRecords() {
    for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
        //Not sure how to print a 'singleRecord' from the 'Records' List
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know how to get an item from a list?

Comment: In `for` loop with index, use `List::get(int index)` method.  Also it is possible to use `for-each` loop: `for (List<String> single : records) { System.out.printf("Name: %s, Age: %d%n", single.get(0), single.get(1)); }`.  There are also iterators and streams to access the list contents.

Comment: @AlexRudenko This approach is too low level to be considered a good design. Java is an Object Oriented language, use objects.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne It may be low level but it is probably appropriate for the OP.  And using an Object still won't show them how to get an element from a list of lists.

Comment: @WJS Learning about a list of lists does not appear to be the question.

Answer (score 4):

So `records.size()` will return the number of Lists stored in your ArrayList `records`, which, from your example, will return `4`. This number can be used to get every List from your ArrayList `records`. Then, it is just a matter of getting all of the elements from that List :).

```
 for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
    List<String> insideList = records.get(i);
    System.out.println("Name: " + insideList.get(0) + ",Age: " + insideList.get(1));
}
```

Since we know that `Name` is on index 0, and `Age` is on index 1, it is safe to print it like this. (Assuming that input file is always correct, but I leave that to you to check that :) )

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest another approach. Define a class Person, with properties name and age, with a constructor which takes name and age, and create a list of Person. Then you can print the list as you wish.

Comment: While theoretically you are correct in recommending to create custom objects from the csv data, the questioner is most likely an inexperienced student who is still learning the basics. Therefore, he/she would be better served if the answer builds on his existing structure.

Comment: @Eritrean On the contrary, he should learn it right from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it following this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
    List<String> singleRecord = records.get(i)
    System.out.println(String.format("Name: %s, Age: %s", singleRecord.get(0), singleRecord.get(1)));
}
```

Or with foreach:

```
for(List<String> singleRecord: records) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Name: %s, Age: %s", singleRecord.get(0), singleRecord.get(1)));
}
```

Comment: This approach is too low level to be considered a good design. Java is an Object Oriented language, use objects.

Comment: Do you have tried it yourself? This doesen't work.

Comment: I made a mistake, insted of using "{}" in String.format() you need to use "%s"